# Is it true that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/m\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has exactly $\text{N}(m)$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gaussian-integers

As the question title suggests, is it true that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/m\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has exactly $\text{N}(m)$ elements?

Comment: What is N($m$)?

Comment: Yes, the cardinality of the quotient is the norm of $m$. If $K$ is a number field and $A$ is its ring of integers, then for any non-zero element $a$ of $A$, the quotient $A/(a)$ has cardinality $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(a)$.

Comment: By the way, are you the same user who asked [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870901) question? If yes, you should [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.